# Multiple Band in a Single Row in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to obtain this kind of layout with this record in jasper and how to do that?

color_table

```
id | color_group | description
1  | primary     | the first
2  | secondary   | the second
3  | tertiary    | the third
```

color_table_details

```
color_table_id | color
1              | red
1              | blue
1              | yellow
2              | orange
2              | violet
2              | green
3              | etc
```

What layout i want is below.

```
id       color group       description           color
1          primary           the first           red
                                                 blue
                                                 yellow
2          secondary         the second          orange
                                                 violet
                                                 green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that with the following solution:

```
1. Added report group to the report
2. Added new variable with type of string (var_name)
3. On the variable expression property of the variable,
    $V{var_name} == null || ${var_name} == ""
    ? "1"
    : ${var_name} + ", 1"
4. Set the reset type of your variable to **Report** and its reset group to the report group you created at step 1
5. Then on your report layout, edit the text field expression of your id, color group and description to the following
    $V{var_name} == "1"
    ? ${field_name}
    : ""
```

Comment: woah i didn't thought this solution would work. Thanks a lot. :)